# RabbitMQ queue gets deleted immediately after creation. Why?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-cloud-services, azure-aks

I'm trying to deploy Spring Boot microservices applications producing and consuming data using RabbitMQ on K8s Cluster in Azure AKS.
When I run producer application and produce a message to the queue through POSTMAN, I get 200 OK response but in RabbitMQ management UI, I get no queues and in the RabbitMQ container logs I see below error

`o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'employeeexchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)`

Not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
If you have any idea (or need any kind of additional information), let me know.

Comment: How did you setup the rabbitmq ?

Comment: 1. Created RabbitMQ service of type LoadBalancer
2. Created headless service for StatefulSets
3. Created RabbitMQ StatefulSet using `rabbitmq:3.7.5-management` image

Comment: Did you create the exchange employeeexchange?

Comment: It is getting created through code. But it gets deleted after few seconds.

Comment: Is it the queue that gets deleted or the exchange that gets deleted? Note in the error message it says explicitly that its the exchange - in vhost '/'.

Comment: Yes, in the error message it says about exchange but both of them get deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below to create a queue

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
return new Queue(String name, boolean durable, boolean exclusive, boolean autoDelete)
```

Parameters:

`name` - the name of the queue.

`durable` - true if we are  declaring a durable queue (the queue will survive a server restart)

`exclusive` - false if we are not declaring an exclusive queue (the queue will only be used by the declarer's connection)

`autoDelete` - false if the server should not delete the queue when it is no longer in use